# How to reference an enum method of constants within another class

Tags: java

I am trying to code certain animals to have directions which are already set within 2 of my main classes, named critter main and critter

```
// constants for directions
public static enum Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, CENTER
};
```

I am creating a class named Ant that inherits critter

```
import java.awt.*; 

public class Ant extends Critter
{
    private boolean walkSouth;
    public Ant (boolean walkSouth){
        this.walkSouth = walkSouth;
    }

    public Color getColor(){
        return Color.RED;
    }

    public boolean eat(){
        return true;
    }

    public Attack fight(String enemy){
        return Attack.SCRATCH;
    }

    int walk = 2;

    public Direction getMove(){
        if(walkSouth == false){
            Direction.EAST;
        }
        if(walkSouth == true){

        }
        return Direction.CENTER;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "%";
    }
}
```

I tried accessing the method by doing

```
Distance d = new Distance();
```

but since this is an enum method, I am confident this is not how I would access these constants, sorry if this a stupid question, I am generally new to this logic of programming

Comment: Where is `Distance` defined? Can't see it at all

Comment: I don't see anything named 'distance'. "how I would access these constants" - you are already doing this e.g. `return Direction.CENTER;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but to answer the question in your title as directly as possible...here's how to reference an enum defined in one class from another class:

```
class Critter {
    // constants for directions
    public static enum Direction {
        NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, CENTER
    };
}

class Foo {
    public void x() {
        Critter.Direction d = Critter.Direction.CENTER;
    }
}
```